# Mapping out values from data Flutter

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I'm having trouble extracting the values of the data received from the push notification:
`Message data: {default: {"event":"text","id":"23Vlj0BwSA7xKtsf4IbFCHAIsNr"}}`, where I tried a lot of `.map` methods etc. but I always get `null` values. Is there an easy approach to get the data from the `message.data`, so I can extract the value of the `event` key and the id value from the `id` key?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with the below code?

```
import 'dart:convert';

const rawJson =
'{"default": {"event":"text","id":"23Vlj0BwSA7xKtsf4IbFCHAIsNr"}}';

void parse() {
  final value = json.decode(rawJson);
  print(value['default']['event']);
  print(value['default']['id']);
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: you can also create a message class and the add a fromJson factory

Comment: I had to make some small changes for it to work, thanks a lot for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sanjay for the help, his solution wasn't working for me but it was close enough, only these 2 small changes worked:

**NOTICE**: Apart from @sanjay's answer I had to change json.decode to `jsonDecode` and I had to put a variable `var` instead of the constant value. I can understand the `var` and `const`, but I'm not sure about the jsonDecode method why I had to change it but it worked like this.

```
var value = jsonDecode(message.data['default']);
      var event = value['event'];
      var id = value['id'];
      print(id);
```

Output:

```
23Vlj0BwSA7xKtsf4IbFCHAIsNr
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great to know that you solved the issue.